# Who is this gargoyle-like character?

Tags: ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3

Who is the circled character, and what source material is he(?) from?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That character appears to be [Firebrand](http://marvelvscapcom.wikia.com/wiki/Firebrand). He actually *is* a gargoyle.

> Firebrand is a type of gargoyle known as a Red Arremer. He will stand up to any threat posed to his home, the Demon Village, without any fear. Firebrand is considered to be an elite warrior among the Red Arremers, gaining him hero status among his peers.

He made his first appearance in *Ghosts 'n Goblins* in 1985.